# How can i use Contours to construct points for perfect Rectangle using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I have points from findContous(). How can i convert them to square rectangle so that i can crop image.

**ArrayList contours = new ArrayList();

             Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

             Imgproc.findContours(panoChange, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);**

I want to eliminate the black top and bottom bars and make the resulting image a perfect sqaure

I am Using Java for OpenCV. Any Help appreciated.
[image]

Comment: can you show a sample image? will you have to decide whether the contour in fact is rectangle-like, or do you just want to find a bounding box for an arbitrary object? if you want to find a bounding box, try `boundingRect` function: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose what you need is the [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html)-method. It creates a bounding rectangle of a point set. To get the bounding rect of all the contours, you can iterate through them.

This example shows how you can crop your image to cover all the contours in the image.

```
        // original mat
        Mat mat = ....

        int top = mat.height();
        int left = mat.width();
        int right = 0;
        int bottom = 0;
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();    
        Imgproc.findContours(copy, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        for(int i=0; i< contours.size();i++){
           if(Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)) < mat.getHeight()*mat.getWidth()){
                Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
                if(rect.x < left){
                    left = rect.x;
                }
                if(rect.x+rect.width > right){
                    right = rect.x+rect.width;
                }
                if(rect.y < top){
                    top = rect.y;
                }
                if(rect.y+rect.height > bottom){
                    bottom = rect.y+rect.height;
                }
            }
        }
        // crop image to the bounding rectangle covering all contours
        Point topLeft = new Point(left, top);
        Point bottomRight = new Point(right, bottom);
        Mat cropped = new Mat(mat, new Rect(topLeft, bottomRight));
```

Remember that if you want to ignore the smallest countours (noise, etc), you can just check if rect area is larger than a specified threshold.

```
if(Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)) < threshold))
```

**EDIT**: The answer may not be relevant after the edit of the question, because it resulted in two different questions. To remove the upper and lower black bars, and also make the output image a square, something like this can be done:

```
int upperBarHeight = ...
int lowerBarHeight = ...
int diff = (mat.getWidth() - mat.getHeight()) / 2;
Point topLeft = new Point(left+diff, top+upperBarHeight);
Point bottomRight = new Point(right-diff, bottom-lowerBarHeight);
Mat cropped = new Mat(mat, new Rect(topLeft, bottomRight));
```

This will crop the same width on both sides to make it square.

Comment: Thanks for response. i have uploaded the image. i want to remove all the top and bottom black bars and output image should be a perfect square

Comment: @Abid: Ohh, I see you edited your post now, so suddenly the question is a little different. If you want to use the contours to crop the image, then you should use the method in my answer. If you simply want to crop your image, just use: Mat croppedImage = new Mat(originalImage, squareRect);

Comment: thank you so much. that refined the image but still the image is not a perfect square. i need to make the output image a sqaure one

Comment: the output still has small black lines

Comment: @Abid: The code example doesn't take into account that the image should be square. I saw that first when you edited your post. And it isn't obvious that using the contours will eliminate the black line. Why cant you just crop the image with a rect that you have specified?

Comment: I have crop the image. but still there are some black bars at the top and bottom! @Ole-M

Comment: How should i send you the output Image.

Comment: @Abid see the edit of my answer. From what I understand from your question, that's about all the help I can give you

Comment: sorry i used wrong word. i meant a perfect rectangle. but still it is helpul. should i send you the output image.